LightningChartJS axises text change default yellow text color
I'm currently using LightningChartJS in my project, and I'm experiencing an issue with the color of the text of the axes. I chose to set the background to whiter theme according to my Figma design but I cant find the property to set the numbers of the axis X and axis Y colors into black so they can be seen!!! I need to see the numbers :(
screen shot

I also look in the docs but couldn't find it
Thanks in advance!
